# 法人で使っているIPアドレスと個人で使っているIPアドレスを見分けられますか?

Tags: ipアドレス

IPアドレスだけから、個人、法人を見分けられますか？
特定の数値が使われているなど、特徴はありますか？

Comment: 無理だと思います。IPアドレスからドメイン名が判る場合には、推測できるかも知れませんが個人でも.comのアドレスを持っていたりしますからね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPアドレスのデータベースは[Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/)が有名です。[無料バージョン](http://dev.maxmind.com/ja/geolite2/)と有料バージョンがあります。[各種言語のライブラリ](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs)もあります。おそらく有料バージョンだと思いますが[接続タイプのDB](https://www.maxmind.com/ja/geoip2-connection-type-database?pkit_lang=ja)で質問主さんの要件の一部は満たせそうです。

僕はIPアドレスから[ASN](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E5%BE%8B%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0_(%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88))を取得して、ユーザーの一番近くのサーバーを割り出すなどの用途に使っています。

Comment: Maxmindで住所は合っていなかったですが、ドメインはわかるのですね。

Comment: GeoIPデータベースはそこそこの精度がありますが、住所を割り出すものではありません。ドメインだけならDNSの逆引きでわかりますよ。

Comment: ドメイン、IPから法人を割り出したかったですが、プロバイダに直接確認するとかでないとやっぱり厳しそうですね、、、

Answer (score 3):

自宅をオフィスにしている個人事業主の場合、どちらとカウントしますか？

ということを考えると質問があいまいで判別不能が答えになると思います。

---

コメントより

> ドメイン、IPから法人を割り出したかった

というのは元質問とずいぶん異なる内容に感じます。[WHOISサービス](http://whois.jprs.jp/)を使用するとIPアドレスの所有者を確認することができます。ある程度、希望に沿った結果が得られると思いますが、前述の例（あくまで一例に過ぎません）ようにあいまいな部分は意図通りの結果かどうかはわかりかねます。

Comment: 「自宅をオフィスにしている個人事業主の場合」は個人とカウントします。

Comment: ざっくりアクセス元の統計を取りたいのかと思ったら、法人を割り出したかったとはね。

Answer (score 0):

求められている答えではないと思いますが、有料のサービスであれば、サイバーエリアリサーチ社が提供しているIP Geolocationデータベース 「SURFPOINT™」のデータを使用すれば判別可能かと思います。

http://www.surfpoint.jp/btob/index.html

SURFPOINT™のデータにはIPアドレス毎に企業かそうでないかのフラグが付与されています。
個人(個人事業主)が使用しているIPアドレスは企業に含まれません。
(プロバイダ所有している個人向けのIPアドレスになるはずなので)

ただし、これはサイバーエリアリサーチ社が独自に調査した結果であり、IPアドレスによる企業判定の結果を保証するものではありません。